# Matching "#word1-word2-word3..."

Tags: java, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

I am very new to regular expressions, and hence was wondering if someone could help me with generating a regular expression to match the following pattern:

#aeronautical-aerospace

so its just a '#' followed by one or more words each separated by a hyphen. I have tried the following regex but am not finding matches:

#\w+-?\w*-?\w*

But I guess this only accounts for a regex with a '#' followed by one, two or three words separated by hyphens. How would I account for a '#' followed by any number of words separated by hyphens?

I once again apologize as I know this is a fairly basic question but I have been looking for good tutorials but although there are many tutorials out there, most of them do a really bad job of explaining regex in a simple manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
#\w+(-\w+)+
```

So this means you want a '#', followed by one or more letters, followed by one or more groups of a hyphen and one or more letters. Let me know if this helps.